# Probability, combinations with repetition

Tags: combinatorics

A store sells n different kinds of fruits. A boy buys k fruits. Find the probability that he buys all the kinds of fruits.

Give me a hint, please.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question. If $k \geq n$ it is $1$, if $k<n$ it is $0$.

Comment: Don't you have any information on the respective quantities of the different fruits?$$$$

Comment: No, I havn't :(I suppose, there are infinitely many fruits of any kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you mean for the store to have an unlimited number of each different kind of fruit.  Are you also assuming that any *multiset* of fruit is equally likely?  That is, the probability of choosing 1 apple, 3 oranges, and 2 bananas is the same as the probability of choosing 6 apples?

This being the case, think of it this way: you must choose at least one of each of the $n$ fruits.  So, to count the number of ways to choose all $k$ fruits - such that each fruit is represented at least once - you really need to count in how many ways you can choose the $k-n$ "extra" pieces.

See if you can make that work.

Comment: So, the probability is $\frac{{k-1}\choose{k-n}}{{n-k+1}\choose k}$ Right? Thank you.

Comment: @Barbara That's right!

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a hint, so I'll give you this:
Assuming the fruits are *indistinguishable* and there are:

- $n$ kinds of fruit
- $m$ number of fruits per type
- $k$ number of fruits bought

The boy can pick any out of $m*n$ fruits the first time. The second time he needs to pick one of the set $m*(n-1)$, since he might not pick the sort he already has, from $mn-1$, since there is one fruit less in the shop.
You might see a series emerging here..
$$\frac{mn}{mn}*\frac{m(n-1)}{mn-1}*\frac{m(n-2)}{mn-2}*\ldots$$
I'll let you have a go now :)

Comment: There is no $m$ in his problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the boy is getting fruits at random, and the supply is unlimited, what are the chances of getting at least one of $K_1$ of fruit?

This is more similar to coin tossing than grabbing things from a set. If we only had 2 fruits, it would be something like:

$$P(K_1) = 1 - (\frac{1}2)^n$$

But since we have k fruits, the chance of the boy to not get fruit of kind $K_1$ is $\frac{k-1}k$:

$$P(K_1) = 1 - (\frac{k-1}k)^n$$

This is 1 minus the chance of never getting kind $K_1$ of fruit n times, which is the opposite of never getting any fruit of kind $K_1$: getting at least one.

And the chance of getting at least one of every fruit?

$$P(K) = P(K_1) P(K_2) ... P(K_k)$$

Since every kind of fruit has the same probability of being picked, then this is equivalent to $P(K_1)^k$

$$P(K) = (1 - (\frac{k-1}k)^n)^k$$

Example:

10 kinds of fruit, 20 tries:

$$P(K) = (1 - (\frac{10-1}{10})^{20})^{10} = 0.273 $$